# Trace undefined variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I'm getting the following error:

```
libs.js:3392 TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of undefined
  at Object.b.updateAutoHeight (http://localhost:3000/.../scripts/libs.js:1529:12362)
  at Object.b.slideTo (http://localhost:3000/.../scripts/libs.js:1530:1740)
  at Object.b.init (http://localhost:3000/.../scripts/libs.js:1530:25098)
  at Object.t (http://localhost:3000/.../scripts/libs.js:1530:27249)
  at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/.../scripts/libs.js:1529:107)
  at Function.each (http://localhost:3000/.../scripts/libs.js:1409:2882)
  at n.each (http://localhost:3000/.../scripts/libs.js:1409:847)
  at n.e.fn.swiper (http://localhost:3000/.../scripts/libs.js:1529:85)
  at Carousel.activate (http://localhost:3000/.../scripts/app.js:1802:34)
  at Carousel.toggleActivation (http://localhost:3000/.../scripts/app.js:1824:57)
```

Now I know the error is that some variable is being passed into a library, that is undefined when it isn't supposed to be. How do I backtrace the variable that is being passed that is undefined?

Comment: Are you using some sort of Carousel plugin, if so, show us the code initializing it. The error tells you where it is, in `libs.js :1529:12362`

Comment: look here first `http://localhost:3000/.../scripts/app.js:1802:34`. is it your file?